# Disable paredit insert space between token and parens

Tags: javascript, emacs, paredit

I like using paredit for my javascript. I know, it's weird, but its helpful to me. The one thing that really bugs me is when I type `foo()` it automatically inserts a space to `foo ()`.

Is there an option to disable this behavior?

Comment: I don't see a customization for this. paredit was designed for editing Lisp, not traditional languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems done by function `paredit-insert-pair`. Commenting out the line in question as shown at last line below does it here.
Writing an own customization in line above might correct value of `spacep` and keep the space for other modes.

Also tweaking function `paredit-space-for-delimiter-p` is an option.

```
(defun paredit-insert-pair (n open close forward)
  (let* ((regionp
          (and (paredit-region-active-p)
               (paredit-region-safe-for-insert-p)))
         (end
          (and regionp
               (not n)
               (prog1 (region-end) (goto-char (region-beginning))))))
    (let ((spacep (paredit-space-for-delimiter-p nil open)))
      ;; (if spacep (insert " "))
```